# Elasticsearch: Aggregating within the document and sorting the documents

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an Elasticsearch index that has JSON documents as shown below:

```
{ "category": "cat001", "items": [{ "item": "item001", "count": 5}, { "item": "item005", "count": 3}]}
{ "category": "cat002", "items": [{ "item": "item002", "count": 4}, { "item": "item001", "count": 3}]}
{ "category": "cat003", "items": [{ "item": "item003", "count": 5}, { "item": "item001", "count": 2}]}
```

I want to add all the counts per category and sort the categories based on the sum of counts in each category. Is this possible? If so, how? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following query:

```
{
 "size" : 0,
 "aggs": {
  "group_by_category": {
      "terms": {
          "field" : "category",
          "order": {
           "sum_of_items": "desc"
        }
      },
      "aggs" : {
       "sum_of_items" : {
           "sum" : {
               "field" : "items.count"
            }
          }
       }
     }
  }
}
```